# could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I was trying out `react-native` with **redux** and I got some issues.

I wrap up the `NavigationContainer` with `Provider` but still getting:

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`

this happens when ever I use selector to select state value and console log it.

[image]

My slice class looks something like this:

[image]

My Store class looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error below is telling you that you are trying to read react-redux context value (store) without first providing the context values.

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`

---

If you need to access redux store in `App` component, you should wrap the `App` component with `<Provider />`, so that it can provide the react-redux context values to `App` and other nested components.

So, you can use `Provider` in `index.jsx` or `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}> {/* HERE */}
      <App /> {/* Now, App is wrapped in Provider and hence can read from store */}
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

After this, you can use `useSelector` (or `connect`) to read redux store in `App` or any other nested component:

```
const countryCode = useSelector(selectCountryCode)
```

Comment: I created my app with expo and i can't find index.js thats why i tried to wrap the App component. Where can i get index.js

Comment: you will have App.js file

Comment: how can i get ReactDOM in react native?

Answer (score 1):

Rename your **App.js** to **Index.js** and create an another **App.js** at same file hierarchy

[image]

now, in **App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/store/DataCentre'
import Index from './Index'

function App(){
    return(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Index/>
    </Provider>

    );
}

export default App
```

**and one last thing restart your expo app from terminal (MUST)**

it works for me if you face any doubt just comment below

**thank you**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in React Native. I also has an expo managed workflow. Below is what solved my issue. Just move the store into the `index.js` file that expo creates.

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';

import App from './App';
import store from './store'; // import your Redux store

    const ReduxApp = () => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );

registerRootComponent(ReduxApp);
```